# List header scroll behavior in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-animated

Wondering how I can achieve this scrolling behavior like Instagram has on their profile pages with React-Native? More specifically, how I do limit the scroll indicator to just the bottom section rendering the posts?

[Instagram scroll behavior](https://media.giphy.com/media/Efe2L56hb1Z1iGioSU/giphy.gif) vs [what I have](https://media.giphy.com/media/3F1buiBpLLco8KyTGq/giphy.gif)

So far these are what I've tried with no success:

1. Using a FlatList with a header component (both sticky and not).
2. Using a SectionList, with a FlatList in one section, but if set `showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}` on the SectionList, the FlatList also does not display the scroll indicator, no matter its value.
3. Also tried using Animated (react-spring) values and translating components based on scroll offset. This is the closest I've been, but it had more of a parallax effect which isn't really what I'm aiming for. Also, the animation was very choppy.

Been trying my hand at this for a couple of days now so any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This is good example of what do you want to implement https://blog.logrocket.com/using-react-native-scrollview-create-sticky-header/

Comment: Thanks @KirillNovikov! I did glance at that article but it seemed similar to the third technique I tried. Maybe worth another look though. Appreciate it!

Comment: Did you find a solution for your problem? Did @KirillNovikov answer do it for you?